# Javascript- getting attributs of the div which is immediately before the concerned div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to get the attributes of the div which is immediately before the div I am calling.

For eg:
[image]

Here I am concerned with  **`divBAMT`** and I need to get the attributes of `pMu$i32`. How can I get the same. The basic idea is, I need to add the `divBAMT` immediately under the div `pMu$i32` and I have done that but I need to position my `divBAMT` accordingly.

So I ll get the attributes of the above div such as top and height and decide the position of my div accordingly.

Is there any other better approach to do the same?

Comment: Try `elementNode.previousSibling`, like `document.getElementById("divBAMT").previousSibling`

Comment: please post code as code, not as image

Comment: Try `var pmu = document.getElementById('pMu$divBAMT').previousElementSibling`; @Cherniv doesn't your above comment also include text nodes?.. realized, yes it does. :)

Comment: Post your code how you add `divBAMT`.

Comment: @Mr_Green good point, need to check..

Comment: Yes, you can't just use `previousSibling` because it will likely be a text node.

Comment: Yes, I meant `previousSibling` :)

Comment: `previousSibling` works.How should I accept an answer from the comments?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer, you can accept now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`elementNode.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling), like:

```
 var prev = document.getElementById("pMu$divBAMT").previousSibling;
 console.log(prev.id); // pMu$i32
```

Working examle: http://jsfiddle.net/RQdcN/

Answer (score 1):

Using **element.previousSibling** is good solution if you are very sure that you don't have any other tags in between both the divs.

**Eg1.**

```
<div id='par'>
   <div id='a'></div>
   <span id='sp'></span>
   <div id='b'></div>
 </div>
```

Applying previousSibling on 'b' div will give span tag instead of the 'a' div

```
document.getElementById('b').previousSibling; // -> span tag
```

Iterating from the bottom till you reach a nearby div tag is a better solution (incase you may have different tags between the divs)

**Solution :**

```
var prevDiv = document.getElementById('b');
do {
  prevDiv = prevDiv.previousSibling;
} while(prevDiv && !(prevDiv.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div' || prevDiv.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div'));

console.log(prevDiv); // Now prevDiv is either null if no divs are found, else the nearest top div sibling
```

Updated fiddle
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R7TE/)